# Ansible: Change default values of nested vars

Tags: dictionary, ansible, nested

I have written a role to create users. Now I wanted to modify the role to also give the option to remove users. What looked very simple in the beginning is now giving me constant headaches.

Here is my role:

```yaml
---
- name: Dictionary playbook example
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_default_values:
        users: &def
            state: 'present'
            force: 'yes'
            remove: 'no'
    my_values:
        users:
            - username: bla
              <<: *def
              state: absent
            - username: bla2
              <<: *def

  tasks:
    - debug: var=my_default_values
    - debug: var=my_values
```

Here is the output:

```
PLAY [Dictionary playbook example] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
        
        TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
        ok: [localhost]
        
        TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
        ok: [localhost] => {
            "my_default_values": {
                "users": {
                    "force": "yes",
                    "remove": "no",
                    "state": "present"
                }
            }
        }
        
        TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
        ok: [localhost] => {
            "my_values": {
                "users": [
                    {
                        "force": "yes",
                        "remove": "no",
                        "state": "absent",
                        "username": "bla"
                    },
                    {
                        "force": "yes",
                        "remove": "no",
                        "state": "present",
                        "username": "bla2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        
PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0
rescued=0    ignored=0
```

This is working fine as long as I always define `<<: *def` below every `- username` in my role. But this is problematic if let's say I want to have the `users` variables defined in an external file *users.yml*. I guess I would need some kind of loop?

In the end I want to use the role with Katello and so the users are defined inside of Katello. This is why I need to get this working in a more dynamic fashion.

Comment: Parameters ``force`` and ``remove`` are **boolean**. Remove the quotes from the values.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two approaches:

If you plan on looping on those users and use the values of the dictionaries, then, just define the adequate default with the purposed [`default` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default):

*roles/demo/tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      user:
        username: "{{ item.username }}"
        state: "{{ item.state | default('present') }}"
        force: "{{ item.force | default('yes') }}"
        remove: "{{ item.remove | default('no') }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.username }}"
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
    - name: demo
      users:
        - username: bla
          state: absent
        - username: bla2
```

Which will yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=bla) => 
  msg:
    user:
      force: 'yes'
      remove: 'no'
      state: absent
      username: bla
ok: [localhost] => (item=bla2) => 
  msg:
    user:
      force: 'yes'
      remove: 'no'
      state: present
      username: bla2
```

---

If you really do need a list inside your role, recreate a new list, combining the the default value to the input given to the role, taking advantage of the fact that, when combining two dictionaries containing the same key, the values of the second dictionary will override the values of the first one:

*roles/demo/tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
- set_fact:
    users_with_default: >-
      {{
        users_with_default | default([])
        + [user_defaults | combine(item)]
      }}
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  vars:
    user_defaults:
      state: 'present'
      force: 'yes'
      remove: 'no'

- debug:
    var: users_with_default
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
    - name: demo
      users:
        - username: bla
          state: absent
        - username: bla2
```

Which will yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  users_with_default:
  - force: 'yes'
    remove: 'no'
    state: absent
    username: bla
  - force: 'yes'
    remove: 'no'
    state: present
    username: bla2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [*module_defaults*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html#module-defaults). It's not necessary to include [state: present](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-state) and [remove: no](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-remove) because these are defaults. In the list *my_users* include only required parameter *name* and parameters with non-default values

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  module_defaults:
    ansible.builtin.user:
      force: yes
  vars:
    my_users:
      - name: foo
        state: absent
      - name: bar
```

In the task, by default [*omit*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) optional [parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameters) that you want to use

```yaml
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.user:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        state: "{{ item.state|default(omit) }}"
        force: "{{ item.force|default(omit) }}"
        remove: "{{ item.remove|default(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_users }}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both. Your solutions look really simple. I spend hours and hours and didn't get this working. I also started by using module defaults, but could not get it to work. I will probably use β.εηοιτ.βε 2nd solution as I want to process the users with additional modules in my role.

Comment: I guess, your main problem is actually in the quotation of the boolean values ``'yes'`` vs. ``yes`` and ``'no'`` vs. ``no``. A non-empty string evaluates to ``True`` in a condition, i.e. also ``'no'`` translates to boolean ``True``.

Comment: Yes that may also have been issue. I finally ended up with a working role. Thanks a lot to you guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

My role finally works. Maybe it is not the best solution, but it does work just fine for what I wanted to achieve:

```
---
# tasks file for securehost

- set_fact:
    users_with_default: >-
      {{
        users_with_default | default([])
        + [user_defaults | combine(item)]
      }}
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  vars:
    user_defaults:
      state: 'present'
      force: 'yes'
      remove: 'no'

- name: Allow 'wheel' group to have passwordless sudo
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    regexp: '^%wheel'
    line: '%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
    validate: 'visudo -cf %s'

- name: create base homedir /lhome with mode 775
  file:
    path: /lhome
    state: directory
    mode: "u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx"

- name: Add / Remove users
  environment: umask=077
  user: name={{ item.username }} uid={{ item.uid }} home="/lhome/{{ item.username }}" groups={{ item.groups }} state={{ item.state }} remove={{ item.remove }} force={{ item.force }}
  with_items: "{{ users_with_default }}"

- name: change mode of all homedirs under /lhome to mode 0700
  file:
    path: "/lhome/{{ item.username }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0700
  with_items: "{{ users_with_default }}"
  when:
    - item.state != 'absent'

- name: Add authorized keys for users
  authorized_key: user={{ item.username }} key="{{ item.key }}" exclusive={{ pubkey_exclusive }}
  with_items: "{{ users_with_default }}"
  when:
    - item.state != 'absent'

- name: Change root password
  user:
   name: root
   password: "{{ root_password_hash }}"
  when: change_root_pw | bool
```

Again thanks a lot for your quick help on this.